# how to find the class that will be executed when Android app is started?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

working on an Android App.  It is quite big and involved.  I need to find the class that will be executed when the App starts up, for example in Eclipse when it is run.  How can I find this class? Is there some standard?

Comment: Your main activity will be the first class to run...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check your `AndroidManifest.xml`, it's located there with the flags:

```
<intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html):

> When you create a new application using the Android SDK tools, the stub activity that's created for you automatically includes an intent filter that declares the activity responds to the "main" action and should be placed in the "launcher" category. The intent filter looks like this:

```
<activity android:name=".ExampleActivity" android:icon="@drawable/app_icon">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

And later:

> The  element specifies that this is the **"main" entry point** to the application. The  element specifies that this activity should be listed in the system's application launcher (to allow users to launch this activity).
>
> If you intend for your application to be self-contained and not allow other applications to activate its activities, then you don't need any other intent filters. Only one activity should have the "main" action and "launcher" category, as in the previous example.

In other words, the activity that has an intent filter with action = "android.intent.action.MAIN" and category = "android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" is the activity that runs first when uses presses you app icon.

Since your project is "quite big and involved", I suggest you get the basics - please read the docs about activities, manifest..

Answer (score 0):

Look at your Manifest.xml file:

```
 <activity
  android:name=".LoginActivity"
 <intent-filter>
                 <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                 <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" /> <-LUNCHER ACTIVITY
  </intent-filter>
 </activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

Look in the AndroidManifest.xml

The activty with action.MAIN and category.LAUNCHER will start first

Answer (score 0):

Some pointers that might help you:

- It's usually called MainActivity
- If it isn't called MainActivity in your case, open AndroidManifest, press ctrl + F and search for "LAUNCHER" to see which class will start up first

Comment: This is not the class which runs first. Application is

Answer (score 0):

look at the java codes. you should be albe to find classes there. I think it is in the src folder